# Codemagic is not able to build for ios

Tags: flutter, codemagic

[image: Codemagic ios build error]

App framework is not found when trying to build the flutter application from code magic.

Comment: Please see "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
, "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"
and
"[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not a Codemagic issue. Check "[flutter build ios failing: ld: framework not found App #32454](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32454)" to find a step-by-step guide how to validate Xcode settings and fix the issue.

Also I'd recommend compare Flutter versions what you use locally and on Codemagic (App Settings > Build > Flutter version)